# Image retrival in phonegap using jquery

Tags: jquery, cordova

can anyone explain the following code?

```
function showImage(){
var imgs = $('#gallery img');
imgs.live('click', function(){
    var title = $(this).attr('title');
    $('#picture h1').text(title);
    $('#pic').html($(this).clone());

    $.mobile.changePage($('#picture'));
});
```

}

Comment: live is deprecated! Use `on`

Answer (score 0):

The code attaches a click event handler to all img elements and displays a single img when it has been clicked.

```
// get all img elements in #gallery
var imgs = $('#gallery img');
// bind a click handler on all img elements
imgs.live('click', function(){
    // get the title attribute of the clicked img
    var title = $(this).attr('title');
    // set h1 text to title and add the clicked img to our new page
    $('#picture h1').text(title);
    $('#pic').html($(this).clone());
    // switch to the new page
    $.mobile.changePage($('#picture'));
});
```

I assume the single img page would look like this:

```
<div data-role="page" id="picture">
    <div data-role="content">
    <h1></h1>
    <div id="pic"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: still would like to know in detail meaning of var imgs = $('#gallery img');

Comment: It returns a jQuery object of all elements matching the selector '#gallery img' (All <img> elements inside ID gallery): http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/